# Access Populating Date for Null Date

Tags: date, ms-access-2000

I have a terminationDate field and obviously it will be null for some records, however access is putting in 1899/12/31 for the null records?

Below is my query

```
FormattedDate: Format([terminationDate], "yyyy/mm/dd")
```

Comment: Are you quite sure you do not have a time element in terminationDate?

Comment: @Fionnuala absolutely, there is no time element involved with this field.

Comment: In MS Access a null date returns null. You need to use the immediate window to find out what your field really contains.

Comment: `SELECT Format(Null, "yyyy/mm/dd") AS FormattedDate` returns an empty string.  So if your `Format` expression returns "1899/12/31", `[terminationDate]` must contain something other than Null.